# How should I show the Developer tab in Excel using Macros? (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a way to open the Import XML option (highlighted below) through a macro command...

[image]

So far, I have tried using `Application.SendKeys ("%lt")` - it works, but only when one has enabled the Developer tab in the ribbon - and sadly, a lot of my users won't have the tab enabled. So I thought If it's possible to toggle this checkbox - (File >> Excel Options >> Show Developer Tab)

[image]

I'll just make the Developer tab visible in my user's Excel, and then use Sendkeys. Or, if this isn't possible, Is there any way I could invoke the Import XML option by any other means in Macro? Invoking the Import XML option is the only reason I am doing all this. Kindly guide... Thanks! :)

Comment: `application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "XmlImport"` should be enough

Comment: Thanks @Rory! Unfortunately, it's giving me an error (https://i.ibb.co/CsBG6Lz/image.png); But when I use Sendkeys (with tab enabled), I do not see this, XML gets imported perfectly... Why is this happening? Kindly guide - Thanks!  :)

Comment: Can you let your macro do the import so the user is not involved ?

Comment: Check this video [Import XML File with FileDialog in Excel VBA](https://youtu.be/M8vwRj5XK-M)

Comment: Hi @CDP1802! I have XML Mappings on my Sheet - I think it would be the best if I let my user select the XML file, and it automatically maps on my sheet. As I said in OP, sendkeys works but tab is the problem; and executeMso is also causing problems... Kindly guide :)

Comment: @ElioFernandes Thanks for the video! Unfortunately, I cannot use it as I already have mappings on my sheet, and my XML is very complex/big too...

Answer (score 0):

You can activate (mode=1) or deactivate (mode=0) the developer tab by changing the **DeveloperTools** option in the registry.

```
Sub Test_DeveloperTab()
    Call setDeveloperTab(1)
End Sub

Sub setDeveloperTab(ByVal mode As Integer)
    Dim regKey As String
    regKey = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\" & Application.Version & "\Excel\options\DeveloperTools"
    
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    
    ' If value is equal to existing or different from 0 or 1 then exit
    Select Case Registry_KeyExists(regKey)
        Case 0: If mode = 0 Then Exit Sub
        Case 1: If mode = 1 Then Exit Sub
        Case Else: Exit Sub
    End Select
    
    ' Late Binding
    Dim oShell As Object: Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
        
    If (mode <> 0 And mode <> 1) Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Developer Tab: Activate \\ Deactivate
    oShell.RegWrite regKey, mode, "REG_DWORD"
    
exitRoutine:
    Exit Sub
    
errHandler:
    Debug.Print Now() & "; " & Err.Number & "; " & Err.Source & "; " & Err.Description
    Resume exitRoutine
End Sub

Function Registry_KeyExists(ByVal regKey$) As Variant
    ' Check if registry key exists
    
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    
    Dim wsh As Object: Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Registry_KeyExists = wsh.RegRead(regKey)
    
    Exit Function
    
errHandler:
    Err.Raise Err.Number, "Registry_KeyExists", Err.Description
End Function
```

Comment: Great! I'll try this solution as soon as possible. Meanwhile, could you kindly guide me on what would happen if the above code is executed even when someone has the tab enabled? If nothing would happen, that'd be great; If it crashes, not so great. Kindly guide :) Thanks again for answering!

Comment: Just updated the code with a new function ``Registry_KeyExists`` to check if the key exists. read all comments and you'll understand.